# issue adding generated binary in AOSP to emulator x86_64

Tags: c, makefile, android-source

I am trying to integrate a project into AOSP (version 12) I created the `android.mk` in the repo where I added other files and I recompiled the project successfully the binary of my project is created in `out/target/product/emulator_x86_64/system/bin` of AOSP, but it is not visible in the emulator

I tried with push and it works but I want an automatic solution so I tried to modify android.mk by adding:

```
$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE): $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE) $(PRODUCT_OUT)/system/bin
    $(hide) cp $< $(PRODUCT_OUT)/system/bin/$(LOCAL_MODULE)
```

but I receive an error during the build:

```
overriding commands for target `out/target/product/emulator_x86_64/sy
stem/bin/easycwmp', previously defined at build/make/core/base_rules.mk:525
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the StackOverlow markup facilities to insert code blocks for code, avoid wrapping, preserve newlines, etc.  Also please cut and paste the _entire_ error message as it appears in the terminal rather than paraphrasing (but, thank you for not using screenshots: this are not appropriate for SO please cut and paste text).

Comment: This doesn't look right: `$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE): $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE)`.  This is saying that the target `$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE)` depends on the prerequisite `$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE)`, or in other words a target depends on itself.  That can't be true.